# Read regular Expression from NFA

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Good evening everyone!
Can someone help me with the following task?
So we have this NFA:
[image: NFA]

I was supposed to create a regular expression out of it. Now the solution says: $a^{+}b^{+}(c|ca^{*}b^{+})^{*}$
Unfortunately I don't understand how this is possible. If I look at the NFA, then we can accept a word that only includes one a without any b's. But the regular expression in the solution does not make that possible.  Or am I missing something?
I also converted the NFA to a DFA however that didn't help much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The RE is wrong. It also includes abcb which is not in the language of the automaton.

Answer (score 1):

The direct edge (a) from initial state 1 to final state 3 is not included in the RE.

Comment: But why is that so? Does that mean, that the RE is wrong?

Comment: @Daisy Sure looks like it.